# how get id of tr and use it in post api request body in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am working with reactjs with axios. Currently, I am using get api to get a list. Each column has a unique id and I want to use this id for a new post API "post request" body.
currently i am clicking on button and open a dialog. in dialog i  submit a form and i want to use tr id in dialog form post body request. currently i m using static id but i want to use dynamic id from tr.

**Button**

```
<Button variant="outlined" color="primary" id={data.id} onClick={handleDialogOpenTwo}>
    Faq
  </Button>
```

**Post api and want to use here**

```
axios.post('https://test3.com/api/faqs',
  { 
    ipoId: '1511',   **i want to use this button id here**
    faqList:[
     { question: this.state.question, 
      answer: this.state.answer,
     }
    ]
  }
)
```

**Dialog**

```
  <Dialog open={isOpenTwo} onClose={handleDialogCloseTwo} className="quistion_Popup">
    {/* <DialogTitle>Confirm</DialogTitle> */}
    <DialogContent>
      <DialogContentText>Add Faq</DialogContentText>
      <FaqPage/>
    </DialogContent>

  </Dialog>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In grid component Get button's `id` by `e.target.id` and set it in a `state`;
then send this `state` as a `props` to `Dialog` components then use it.

```js
<button id="test" onClick={(e) => setState(e.target.id)}>Test Button</button>
```

Comment: can you please help me @Hossein i am ready to pay. please

Comment: I am very eager to help more but I do not have much time. Sorry.

Read more about `state` and `props` in react. it's easy.